# Copying year only from date field to another field

Tags: python, gis

I am trying to copy the year only from a date field with `month/day/year` to another field that will have `year` only.  I am not having luck extracting just that portion that I need.
When I read the date field the following returns:

```
(datetime.datetime(1989, 8, 28, 0, 0),)

(datetime.datetime(1984, 9, 27, 0, 0),)
```

I have tried reading the first 4 as both integers and a string

I know that this should be very simple, but with just 1 class under my belt I am struggling.  Hopefully I have included enough without including too much.

I have tried reading the first 4 as both integers and a string.  I have also tried to make `datetime.isoformat` work.

```
table=r'Y:Data.gdb\SDSample'

newdata={}
with open(table, 'wb') as fp:
    writer=csv.DictReader(fp)
    for row in writer:
        year= int(row['first_Date'])
        newdata[year]=row

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table,  field_names=['first_Date', 
'Record_Year']) as updater:    
    for row in updater:
        #extract year (first 4 didgits) from date 
        first = row[0][:4]

        #insert into Record_Year field
        row[1]=first
        updater.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datetime "t" variable you should just do year = t.year

Answer (score 0):

if `x = datetime.datetime(1989, 8, 28, 0, 0)`, to get the year, you can do `x.year` which outputs 1989. hopefully that helps.